# How do I use PHP to compare one variable to any odd number instance of another variable?

Tags: php

I want to compare the session[name] to all the even instances of text.

For example:

```
$_SESSION['name'] === $text[1] or $text[2] or $text[4] or $text[6]
```

The problem with doing it like the way above is that the code above will limit to only 6. Is there any way to just say "compare this to all the even instances of '$text' "?

Basically what I'm trying to do is say:

> Compare $_SESSION['name'] to all even info from the $Text array.

So for example if this was my array:

```
$text = array("info0", "info1", "info2", "info3")
```

I would want to compare something to all the even info instances in the array(ie: info0, info2)

The code:

```
//compare the strings
if ($_SESSION['name'] === $text[0] && $_SESSION['pass'] == $text[1]) {
    //echo "That is the correct log-in information";
    header("Location: home.php");
} else {
    echo "That is not the correct log-in information.";
}
```

Comment: the problem is that's simply invalid php to start with, `in_array()` comes to mind

Comment: do you know how to make a for loop in php? because a for loop would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkEvenValues($text)
{
    if($_SESSION['name'] === $text[1]) return true;
    for($i = 2; $i < count($text); $i += 2)
    {
         if($_SESSION['name'] === $text[$i])
              return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will return true on the first instance. Use a variable to store the result, return at the end - and use strict comparison as the OP does.

Comment: Also, his example includes **1** too, even though its not an even number.

Answer (score 0):

XaxD's answer is good, and probably what you are interested in, but if you are using an associative array and want to look at every other element of the array this will work:

```
function checkEvenValues($text)
{
    $skip = array(true, false);

// set $iskp to 0 if you want the first element to be counted as even; else, set it to 1
    $iskp = 0;   
    foreach ($text as $idx=>$val)
    {
        $skp = 1 - $skp;
        if ($skip[$iskp]) continue;
        if($_SESSION['name'] == $text[$i]) return (true); 
    }
    return (false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that your keys are the same as the numbers in your values (`[0] => 'info0'`) etc, you can use something like this combining some PHP array functions to filter down to only even keys (including 1), then a **strict** `in_array()` check to determine if it's there:

```
function compareEvens($text, $compare) {
    // swap keys for values (back again)
    $evens = array_flip(
        // apply custom filter function
        array_filter(
            // swap keys for values
            array_flip($text),
            // return if its even OR its one
            function($key) {
                return $key % 2 === 0 || $key === 1;
            }
        )
    );

    return in_array($compare, $evens, true);
}
```

[Example:](https://eval.in/179490)

```
$text = array("info0", "info1", "info2", "info3");
var_dump(compareEvens($text, 'info2')); // true
var_dump(compareEvens($text, 'info3')); // false
```

Docs:

- [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)
- [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
- [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)