# How would I make this more efficient ( Not repeat the same thing over and over again)?

Tags: php

**How should i clean up/make more efficient the "Compare this string' part of my PHP?**

```
    <?php 
session_start();

     $_SESSION['name']  = $_POST['name'];
     $_SESSION['pass']  = $_POST['password'];

     //read the contents of our password file.
     $myFile = "password.txt";
     $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
     $data = fgets($fh);
     fclose($fh);

     //echo the data from the text file - I've edited this out so it doesn't display the data
    //echo $data;

     //print out an HTML line break
     //print "<br>";

     //now we need to split our line of data from the text
     //file so that we can do the comparison.

     //split the text into an array
     $text = explode(":",$data);

     //echo the split user name  - I've edited this out so it doesn't display the data
     //echo $text[3];

     //print out an HTML line break
     print "<br>";

     //echo the split password  - I've edited this out so it doesn't display the data
     //echo $text[1];

     //assign the data to variables
     $good_name = $text[0].$text[2];
     $good_pass = $text[1].$text[3];

     //print out an HTML line break
     //print "<br>";

     //compare the strings
     if( $_SESSION['name'] === $text[0] && $_SESSION['pass'] === $text[1] or $_SESSION['name'] === $text[2] && $_SESSION['pass'] === $text[3] or  $_SESSION['name'] === $text[4] && $_SESSION['pass'] === $text[5]){
        //echo "That is the correct log-in information";
        header("Location: home.php");
     }else{
        echo "That is not the correct log-in information.";
     }
  ?>
```

I don't want to have to add a whole new **OR** instance every time i add a new user as is being done in my current code. Is there any way to make it more efficient?

Comment: If you want to stick to text file(s): Read the lines of the file into an array and use `foreach` to loop over them. This assumes you're having one pair of `username:hashedPass` per line in your file. Also: I hope `$_SESSION['pass']` aswell as the text file itself only contain hashes of the password? Otherwise just use a real database (mysql or something similar) and query it using PDO.

Comment: How is the `password.txt` file filled?

Comment: it is filled like this: user:password:admin:password:Me:MyPass

It is exploded at ":" and thus makes each username an even number value and each correlating password an odd numb value.

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, [How do I use PHP to compare one variable to any odd number instance of another variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319128/how-do-i-use-php-to-compare-one-variable-to-any-odd-number-instance-of-another-v)

Comment: Yes I feel like i didn't properly explain what i wanted in the previous question. I flagged it, it didnt let me delete it.

Comment: Can you change the content of the txt file? For example to `user:pass;user:pass;user:pass`?

Comment: you could, you know, use a database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be better to rearrange your `password.txt`, splitting the users by `;` and the username and password by `:`, for example: `user1:pass1;user2:pass2`. Then you could use this code:

```
<?php
session_start();

//read the contents of our password file.
$myFile = "password.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$data = fgets($fh);
fclose($fh);

$temp = explode(';',$data); // split the file into user:pass
$users = array();
foreach( $temp as $userdata) {
    $user = explode(':', $userdata); // split username and pass
    $users[ $user[0] ] = $user[1]; // put it in an array
}


if( isset( $users[ $_POST['name'] ] ) and $users[ $_POST['name'] ] == $_POST['password']  ) {
     $_SESSION['name']  = $_POST['name'];
     $_SESSION['pass']  = $_POST['password'];
     header("Location: home.php");
}
else {
     echo "That is not the correct log-in information.";
}
?>
```

First, the content is loaded from the file. The content will be split on every `;`. Then we loop to every row of that array splitting it to user and password.

The username and password are put in an new array `$users`.

The only thing left is to check if the username exists in the array, and if the password corresponds with it.

You'd also better put the data in a session, after the login.

Comment: How would i put the new data in a session? Ugh there is still so much more PHP to learn...

Comment: You already had it covered with `$_SESSION['name']  = $_POST['name'];`. But I recommend to only do that after the login. Otherwise if the login fails, the data is already stored in a session.

Comment: So i tried out this code and it's not working because it expects the username and password to be the same thing. So it will only allow the login if i enter user:user instead of user:pass . I think it's because of the Name to Pass comparison being done in line 17(if isset), any ideas how to make it do something like this: "If the userentered username is the same as an of the usernames on file and the userentered password is the same as the password for that user on file then redirect to home.php"?

Comment: Yup! It's perfect now! Although as many people suggested, i should probably learn mySQL too so onto that now :p Thanks so much though!

Comment: Yes, it is safer to save your *encrypted* passwords in a database. It also is much more flexible. Good luck with learning :)

Answer (score 1):

For starters: **Don't store plaintext passwords**. Not in any database and certainly not in a text file.

So, what I gather from your comments is that you have 1 line of text in your file that contains alternating fields for usernames and passwords delimited by a colon.

In that case:

```
$data = file_get_contents("password.txt");
$data = explode(":", $data);

if (count($data) % 2 != 0)  // Error, no even number of fields in password file
    return;

$loggedIn = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data) / 2; $i += 2)
{
    $user = $data[$i];
    $pass = $data[$i + 1];

    if ($user == $_SESSION['name'] && $pass == $_SESSION['pass'])
    {
        $loggedIn = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($loggedIn)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

I really recommend not using a text file password approach and read some MySQL / PDO tutorials.

You'd also have to make sure that no usernames / passwords contain a colon.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [Regular Expressions](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) is what you're looking for.

According to your comment on your Question, here's some example code of what I'm thinking about:

```
$file = 'user:password:admin:password:Me:MyPass';
$name = preg_quote($_SESSION['name']);
$pass = preg_quote($_SESSION['pass']);
preg_match("/" . $name . ":" . $pass . "/", $file);
```

You'll have to parse the whole contents of the file at once. [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php) should help here aswell.

But overall: **Never** store plaintext passwords. You always should hash them with a cryptographically strong hashing algorithm. Don't use MD5, don't use SHA. Consider using bcrypt, scrypt or PBDKF2 with a high cost and preferably a salt aswell.

And anyways: Use Databases, they make your life easier ;)